# building astyanax from source on windows does not work

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Getting-Started

the commands listed are:
 1. git clone git@github.com:Netflix/astyanax.git
 2. cd astyanax
 3. ./gradlew build

which product the permission denied error:

C:\Users\windowsuser\Downloads\Astyanax>git clone git@github.com:Netflix/astyanax.git
Cloning into 'astyanax'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.129' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

C:\Users\windowsuser\Downloads\Astyanax>

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a SSH keypair set up and associated on *both* your client machine *and* your own Github account, you will receive that error message.  It's not Windows specific; I was able to reproduce on Linux.

Use `git clone https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax.git` for cloning anonymously.

Comment: Thank you so much, this saved me a ton of headache.